# STL exports wrong geometry

Tags: export, extrude, stl

Blender 4.1 under Ubuntu 23.04.
I created this object:

[image]

but when I export it to STL it seems has some wrong geometries as Cura highlights them in red:

[image]

actually, the printing misses completely both sides:

[image]

Surely I did something wrong in my design. Would you please help me to understand my mistake?

Here my approach:

1. create a plane on XZ
2. subdivide
3. edit and give a "V" shape
4. extrude along Y axis
5. make a loop cut close to the ends
6. make bridges between opposite vertex along the "V" edges
7. select edges and fill to make faces (in order to create the end walls)
8. bevel edges as desired

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some inverted normals on that object which is probably what is causing the problem. On the <kbd>Viewport Overlays</kbd> menu, check the <kbd>Face Orientation</kbd> option. The red faces show the flipped normals.

[image]

Hit <kbd>A</kbd> in <kbd>Edit</kbd> mode to select all then use <kbd>Shift-N</kbd> to recalculate the normals. For some reason that misses a few of the faces as shown below:

[image]

There's also one inside the object. Select all those faces using <kbd>Shift-click</kbd> in <kbd>Face</kbd> mode (<kbd>1</kbd> on the keyboard)  and then use <kbd>Alt-N</kbd> > <kbd>Flip</kbd> to recalculate them correctly. The whole object should then be blue.
I don't know how you created that part of your object, but for some reason the other end of it is correct!

Comment: Following your instructions I was able to fix it! Now it's printing, thanks!

Comment: Good! You're welcome.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I selected the loopcut edges and grab them along the Y axis (in order to change the width of the long slot). After, I had to flip again *some* faces, not all the same of the initial file. Is it expected?

Comment: Without another Blend file or images We can't really tell what's going on, especially as we don't know what 'loopcut edges' you're talking about.